# How to find out where sharepoint is running from?

Tags: sharepoint

Our team has a sharepoint website and I need to maintain the shared documents on our site. Problem is, it was designed by someone else and I was just given the link to the team website. I have tried using search and setting alerts and both of these don't work. i googled trying to find out what's happening and everyone keeps asking me to go to central administrator. I don't see central administrator anywhere in the website(I have full access). I am thinking I have to go to the server where sharepoint is running from. How do I figure out where it is running from? Sorry, I'm new to sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Central Admin is the website that SharePoint creates when you install the software.  It generally runs on your main SharePoint web frontend.  If you RDC to your main web front end and then click on Start, All Programs and then click on the SharePoint folder, you'll see Central Administration.  Click on that and the website will appear.  You must be a farm admin to be able to access the site.

It sounds like you may not be a farm admin though.  Depending on the permissions you have, you should be able to see your team site's Shared Documents or other document libraries under All Site Content, which you can either see by clicking on Site Actions or find it on the bottom left of the web page (again depends on what modifications have been created).

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to assign the sign-in user account the permission to check the Shared Documents and you need to get at least Contribute permission level to maintain the Shared Doc on the site.
2. For Central Administrator, you can either RDC to the Web Front End server where the SharePoint was intalled or visit that server IP:port or computer name:port(80 by default).

Hope this may help!

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all,the link you got may not be a Central Administration link.It is probably a common site collection.If you have full control permission over this site collection, you should be able to maintain Shared Document.
2. About the question that where SharePoint is running from?
   SharePoint must be installed in a server. Generally, only farm admin can access this machine. If you want to know or learn about it, and if you don't have farm account to access the server, you can contact your farm administrator.
3. Central Administration is also a site.But it is different. You can manage all web applications and site collections in Central Administration.So you can manage or modify your team site in Central Administration

Hope this helps.